# IOS splash shown while going in foreground from notification center

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking, nsnotificationcenter

I'm experiencing some problem when application is going to foreground after tapping a Notification Center item: the iPhone (and simulator) is actually showing the app icon  stretched to fit the whole screen, instead of using either a) default.png image b) render of the last view before going in background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  your default image name starts with upper case 'D' as in Default.png

Comment: it does starts upper case, then at app boot images is shown correctly, only after Notification Center i have the problem